# How to create a dynamic request in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a response from an API

```
[{
"userSourceMeta": {
    "userId": "sss@gmail.com",
    "source": "BOX",
    "organisationId": 1,
    "emailId": "sss@gmail.com",
    "sourceUserId": "15548727375",
    "accessToken": null,
    "refreshToken": null,
    "lastCursorPosition": null,
    "lastAccessTime": 1626025027228,
    "name": "John",
    "createdAt": 1622444279509
},
"connectionStatus": null}, {
"userSourceMeta": {
    "userId": "test@gmail.com",
    "source": "ONEDRIVE",
    "organisationId": 1,
    "emailId": "sss@outlook.com",
    "sourceUserId": "3969b928a1a28f34",
    "accessToken": null,
    "refreshToken": null,
    "lastCursorPosition": null,
    "lastAccessTime": 1626025027228,
    "name": "sss ddd",
    "createdAt": 1624262423446
},
"connectionStatus": null}]
```

I have to use two parameters in the successive request(source,sourceUserId) . This is a dynamic request it can be varied 3, 4,5 ..etc.

Next API request.

```
{
"Answer": "My name is xyz",
"queryChannel": "WEB_APP",
"timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
"sourceFilterInfo": [{
    "sourceUserId": "15548727375",
    "source": "BOX"
}, {
    "sourceUserId": "3969b928a1a28f34",
    "source": "ONEDRIVE"
}],
"contextIds": []
```

}

Please provide a solution to send a dynamic request with the previous API response.
I used regular expression extractor to store values. But how to send it in a request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   def sourceFilterInfo = []
   response.each { entry ->
       def user = [sourceUserId: entry['userSourceMeta'].sourceUserId, source: entry['userSourceMeta'].source]
       sourceFilterInfo.add(user)
   }

   def payload = [:]

   payload.put('Answer', 'My name is xyz')
   payload.put('queryChannel', 'WEB_APP')
   payload.put('timeZone', 'Asia/Calcutta')
   payload.put('sourceFilterInfo', sourceFilterInfo)
   payload.put('contextIds', [])

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
2. That's it, now you should be able to refer the generated request as `${payload}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)